# split column containing nested lists in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[[0,0]], 'y':[[[1,3,5], [2,4,6]]]})
```

I'd like to split `y` into 3 columns such as this:

```
      x       y_x     y_y     y_z   
0  [0, 0]   [1, 2]  [3,4]   [5, 6]
```

What's the best way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check

```
out = df.join(df.y.apply(lambda x : pd.Series(zip(x[0],x[1]))))
Out[452]: 
        x                       y       0       1       2
0  [0, 0]  [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]  (1, 2)  (3, 4)  (5, 6)
```

Comment: You beat me to it! I'd suggest `pd.Series(zip(*x))` though :)